# When is MCMC required?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

I am trying to understand when MCMC algorithms are utilized. I can do density estimation with MLE for non-linear cases just like linear cases, and EM for hidden variables and missing values. What are the scenarios when these tools are not sufficient and we use MCMC?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Got too long for a comment, so I guess it has to be an answer.

Is MCMC ever actually *required*? I don't think so. There's nearly always some way of proceeding without it.

Sometimes, one or another MCMC algorithm is quite convenient, where alternatives are not so convenient.

Here's one example:

To my mind a big part of what makes MCMC especially convienient - particularly with things like Gibbs and variations (Metropolis-within-Gibbs, block Gibbs etc) is the ability to construct components of models piece by piece as if everything else were okay. So you might have a tool for variable selection or selection of model order, and you might have a tool for dealing with outliers, and you might have a tool for dealing with estimation and you might have a tool for dealing with changing variance, but such procedures usually rely on everything else being either absent, or known rather than estimated.

What makes an outlier an outlier depends on your model, ... but what are the properties of your variable selection if you haven't controlled for outliers? If you do first one and then the other and then some of the first again... what are the properties of that?

MCMC often lets you work with those components conditionally on knowing the other things that would be inconvenient if you didn't know them (while still allowing you to integrate out the things it's convenient to integrate out). If you can establish that the particular details of the sampler you use converges to the desired stationary distribution (trivial if you do something standard, usually not difficult otherwise) and you actually iterate to effective convergence to it (rather harder to assess), then you are sampling from the stationary distribution (in a Bayesian context, typically the desired joint distribution of all your unknowns, from which you can extract the marginals).

That's by no means even remotely exhaustive - for example, I haven't touched on the quite different kind of convenience that Random Walk Metropolis-Hastings can give.

The best way to really begin to understand the value in MCMC is to use it on a few real problems that are otherwise relatively hard.

Comment: Wow. That was kind of abstract. Maybe you can give a toy example or reference to one for me to better visualize. Especially something that illustrates why the other tools won't work.

Comment: 1) Your question was quite broad (indeed so much so I debated voting to close it on that basis). Unless you want a book (or more likely, ten books) as an answer, the answer is also going to be pretty general. 2) I made it very clear right up front that "the other tools won't work" isn't the central issue; usually it's about what's convenient - I don't know that there's *anything* that couldn't at least theoretically be done in *some* other way. 3) If you seek references and examples, you should probably edit that into the question, so other respondents see what you're after.

Comment: What kind of example would you seek? For example, would say "Wood, S. and Kohn, R. (1998), 'A Bayesian approach to robust nonparametric binary Regression', *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, **93**, 203-213" give you a sense of the kind of thing you can do? (You can find a working paper of that online if you search by the title.) If that's not what you want, can you narrow it down a bit? I am not sure what you want.

Comment: Alternatively, something like "Chen, Q., Gerlach, R. and Lu, Z. (2012), 'Bayesian Value-at-Risk and expected shortfall forecasting via the asymmetric Laplace distribution', *Computational Statistics and Data Analysis: Special Issue on Computational and Financial Econometrics*, vol.56:11, pp. 3498–3516"? Or are you after something more like introductory papers, rather than ones that deal with problems where you might really want to use MCMC?

Comment: I am looking for something introductory. But not like something that starts showing some algorithm. More like a tutorial explaining why they are doing it that way.

Comment: If you want something introductory you can't hope to have a problem you couldn't reasonably do some other way. The restriction of NOT giving you something that starts showing algorithms eliminates pretty much every paper I know (and that must be a couple of hundred papers). How can a paper about an algorithm *not discuss the algorithm*? That would mean only speaking about it in general terms ... which wasn't what you wanted, remember?

Comment: You're basically giving several sets contradictory requirements - 1) it must be introductory, but at the same time be something that shows an application you couldn't do any other way; 2) it can't be in general terms (or my original answer should be acceptable), yet ... while (by its very nature!) discussing MCMC algorithms, it can't actually discuss any specific algorithms. What the heck am I supposed to do?

Comment: I suggest you might need to think more about what your central question is, and edit the question as needed.

Comment: Will do so. Don't get upset about it please. I don't know the area at all that's why I am vague.

Comment: Points 1,2,5 and 6 under *What makes a good Cross Validated question?* in [this meta answer](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/1483/805) might help.

Answer (score 1):

MCMC changed Bayesian inference forever, allowing us to go well beyond inference based on conjugate priors. We may see MCMC as a set of tools that allows us to explore any posterior distribution, even when we don't know the analytic expression of its normalization constant (this is analogous to those situations in Physics in which we don't have an analytic expression for the partition function). MCMC gives you a sample of (generally dependent) parameter values from the posterior distribution. From this sample, with the help of the ergodic theorem, any posterior summary can be computed, such as the posterior expectation, a credible interval (more generally, a credible set), or the posterior probability of events involving any (measurable) transformation of the parameters. The existence of a plethora of MCMC methods is due to the fact that, although algorithms like Metropolis-Hastings are pretty much universal, particular algorithms may perform better in specific scenarios. To develop a taste for the need and importance of MCMC, I would do all the possible computations with conjugate priors (books by Robert, Lee, De Groot and Schervish, and others are good starting points), and then proceed slowly to more general problems (Robert and Casella is the best MCMC reference that I have seen so far).

Comment: Are we looking at an online update context? Is that the reason we need MCMC?

Comment: Hi, Cagdas. What's your experience with Bayesian inference?

Comment: Not much I would say. I only know a little under the context of Solomonoff universal prior. But never applied it.

Comment: Cagdas: I would start with simple conjugate cases like a binomial model with beta prior, do as much as possible analytically and then try to handle non-conjugate priors. This will you give a good feeling about the need and value of MCMC methods.

Comment: Actually at the end I would like to understand Particle Filters. I am trying to understand the how nonlinearity and non-gaussian setting brings MCMC to table.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, on PF check out https://hypergeometric.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/illustrating-particle-filters-and-bayesian-fusion-using-successive-location-estimates-on-the-unit-circle/